# cbind error while building Pareto/NBD Model in R (BTYD Package)

Tags: r, model, statistics

I am building a CLV model using the BTYD package and I have hit a roadblock that I just can't seem to get around.

I have been carefully following the directions from Section 2.1 in [this tutorial](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BTYD/vignettes/BTYD-walkthrough.pdf). Everything seemed to be going fine until I got to the calibration customer-by-sufficient-statistic matrix  (cal.cbs).  I used the following code to generate cal.cbs, as instructed in the tutorial:

```
birth.periods <- split.data$cust.data$birth.per
last.dates <- split.data$cust.data$last.date
cal.cbs.dates <- data.frame(birth.periods, last.dates, end.of.cal.period)
cal.cbs <- dc.BuildCBSFromCBTAndDates(cal.cbt, cal.cbs.dates, per="week")
```

Everything seemed to work until the last line.  R gave me the following message:

```
> cal.cbs <- dc.BuildCBSFromCBTAndDates(cal.cbt, cal.cbs.dates, per="week")
Started making calibration period CBS...
Finished building CBS.
Warning message:
In cbind(f, r, T) :
  number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 2)
```

I don't know if this is a huge deal or not because I'm not entirely sure what it means...  I decided to ignore it until I tried to do the parameter estimations.  This is what happened:

```
> params <- pnbd.EstimateParameters(cal.cbs)
Error in optim(logparams, pnbd.eLL, cal.cbs = cal.cbs, max.param.value = 
    max.param.value,  : 
L-BFGS-B needs finite values of 'fn'
In addition: Warning message:
In log(exp(loga - logb) - 1) : NaNs produced
```

I really don't know where to go from here. I looked in the source code for the pnbd.EstimateParameters function, but I couldn't figure out what exactly was going wrong.  Does anybody have even the slightest clue how I might fix this? Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated, as I am completely stuck right now.

Answer (score 2):

Change this line:

```
tot.cbt <- dc.CreateFreqCBT(elog)
```

to this:

```
tot.cbt <- dc.CreateFreqCBT(elog.cal)
```

Answer (score 1):

So Ive actually been having the exact same issue and I got the code to work for the sample data no problem... however for my own data I am having the issue as described above... my thought is that there r, value doesnt match up with the f and T values in length and its therefore returning an error.... thoughts?

So I figured out the issue... basically your data sets do not match up in length... ie the vectors arent of the same length (rows)... you are most likely creating the cbt from the original elog and NOT elog.cal... try this and I am sure it will work... also make sure to scrub your initial data set of NAs...

Hope this helps!
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

This error can occur when the elog contains an odd number of dates.  In that case, when splitting the calibration and holdout periods using `dc.ElogToCbsCbt`, the resulting `holdout$cbt` and `cal$cbt` will be vectors of differing lengths (off by one).

This is an issue in the current BTYD package in CRAN.  However, a workaround is to trim one day of transactions off your elog before you run `dc.ElogToCbsCbt`.

Answer (score 0):

I ran through the example code and got everything right. I assume that whatever was wrong has been fixed in the latest update.

Here's the code from the example:

```
require(BTYD)
cdnowElog <-system.file("data/cdnowElog.csv", package ="BTYD")
elog <- dc.ReadLines(cdnowElog, cust.idx = 2,date.idx = 3, sales.idx = 5)
elog$date <-as.Date(elog$date,"%Y%m%d")
elog <- dc.MergeTransactionsOnSameDate(elog)
end.of.cal.period <- as.Date("1997-09-30")
elog.cal <- elog[which(elog$date <= end.of.cal.period), ]
split.data <- dc.SplitUpElogForRepeatTrans(elog.cal)
clean.elog <- split.data$repeat.trans.elog
freq.cbt <- dc.CreateFreqCBT(clean.elog)
freq.cbt[1:3, 1:5]
tot.cbt <- dc.CreateFreqCBT(elog)
cal.cbt <- dc.MergeCustomers(tot.cbt, freq.cbt)
birth.periods <- split.data$cust.data$birth.per
last.dates <- split.data$cust.data$last.date
cal.cbs.dates <- data.frame(birth.periods, last.dates,end.of.cal.period)
cal.cbs <- dc.BuildCBSFromCBTAndDates(cal.cbt, cal.cbs.dates,per="week")
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error as below but fortunately I found the reason for my case and I hope it works for you too.

```
> Error in optim(logparams, pnbd.eLL, cal.cbs = cal.cbs, max.param.value
> = 
>     max.param.value,  :  L-BFGS-B needs finite values of 'fn'
```

The data cal.cbs contains three columns: x, t.x, T.cal. Make sure that x<=T.cal, i.e. you cannot have more transaction than the total number of time period the user is observed. For example, if you have more transaction per day, you have to collapse them into one traction.

Check if the code below could work for you.

```
> sel = cal.cbs$x < cal.cbs$T.x 
> cal.cbs1 = cal.cbs[sel,]
> params  = pnbd.EstimateParameters(freq.cal.cbs1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same errors and I was able to fix it by replacing below

> tot.cbt <- dc.CreateFreqCBT(elog.cal) #used elog.cal instead of elog

However, I am having issues with :

> sel = cal.cbs$x < cal.cbs$T.x

```
     > Error in cal.cbs$x : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

> sel = cal.cbs$x < cal.cbs$t.x

```
     > Error in cal.cbs$x : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

In the cal.cbs, column is t.x NOT T.x. I don't know what went wrong here. Does any body know how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: cal.cbs is a matrix, not a data.frame, @sharp.  There are appropriate solutions above

Answer (score 0):

sel = cal.cbs$x < cal.cbs$T.x

use cal.cbs[,1] "< "ca;.cbs[,2] or convert to a data frame and use "$"

Answer (score 0):

`cal.cbs` is a matrix not a dataframe.

Try this:

```
sel = cal.cbs[,1] < cal.cbs[,2]

cal.cbs1 = cal.cbs[(sel=TRUE),]

params  = pnbd.EstimateParameters(freq.cal.cbs1)
```

---

there is a function available which performs all the steps at once , from event log to cbs matrix step .
It worked nicely for me .

data<-dc.ElogToCbsCbt(elog, per = "week",T.cal, T.tot = max(elog$date),merge.same.date = TRUE, cohort.birth.per = T.cal,dissipate.factor = 1, statistic = "freq")

for getting  cal.cbs matrix ,use:

data$cal$cbs